# How to find a 3x3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation, matrix-equations

How would you find a $3 \times 3$ matrix given that it scales everything on the plane $x + 2y + 3z = 0$ once, and scales $[0, −1, 1]$ twice.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics! Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: What do you means exactly with : scale once?

Comment: Can you clarify your question, specifically this part, what does scaling means; are you saying that the eigenvalues are 1?

Comment: scaling meaning multiplies by, so it multiplies the plane by 1 and the vector by 2

Comment: is this as straightforward as having a matrix 
[ 1  0  0 
  2 -2  0
  3  2  0 ] ?

Comment: Hint: This is to say, $[0,-1,1]^T$ is one of the eigenvectors of the matrix with eigenvalue $2$, and the another two eigenvectors are any two spanning vectors of the plane with eigenvalue $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so we have to do some diagonalization.

The vectors that make up the plane $x+2y+3z=0$, are the two vectors that are orthogonal to $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\2\\3 \end{bmatrix}$, which are $v_2=\begin{bmatrix} -2\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $v_3=\begin{bmatrix} -3\\-6\\5 \end{bmatrix}$.

Now, we know that the eigenvectors $v_2$ and $v_3$ have eigenvalue $1$.

And the eigenvector $v_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\-1\\1 \end{bmatrix}$

So our eigenvalue matrix  is $D=\begin{bmatrix} 2&0&0 \\ 0&1&0 \\ 0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$

We also have the eigenvector matrix which is $P=\begin{bmatrix} 0&-2&-3 \\ -1&1&-6 \\ 1&0&5 \end{bmatrix}$

Our transformation matrix will be $T=PDP^{-1}$.

Therefore, $T=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0 \\ -1&-1&-3 \\ 1&2&4 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: guys i had a quiz on this today and i failed

Comment: I might’ve taken $v_3=(-3,0,1)^T$ instead, which can be read directly from the equation/normal vector. Since you’re have to invert $P$ anyway, there’s not much to be gained by having an orthogonal basis for the plane. More zeros make for less work :)

Comment: right! in a similar manner to what i did to get the first vector. thanks!! @amd